# Regex // Extract value from <a> link

Tags: regex, curl

I am trying to extract the username :

```
preg_match_all("/\<a href\=\"/Users\/(\D+)\/\"\>(.*)\<\/a\>", $file_content, $matches);
```

from the following

```
<a href="/Users/stackoverflow">stackoverflow</a>
```

But it displays nothing :(

Could you tell me what is wrong there, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unnecessary `\/` included in your regex and you don't need to escape `<` or `>` or `=`. So change your regex like below,

```
<a href=\"/Users\/(\D+?)\">(.*)<\/a>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xY1lW8/2)

```
"/\<a href\=\"/Users\/(\D+)\/\"\>(.*)\<\/a\>"
                           ^
                           |
```

Turning `(\D+)` to a non-capturing group would left with a single group.

```
<a href=\"/Users\/(?:\D+?)\">(.*)<\/a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the help and the useful link :)

Here is my final code :

```
$matches = array();

preg_match_all("<a href=\"/Users\/(\D+?)\">", $file_content, $matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $child) {
   echo $child . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a forward slash in your match string which is not there in the data you're trying to match:

```
preg_match_all("/\<a href\=\"/Users\/(\D+)\/\"\>(.*)\<\/a\>", $file_content, $matches);
                                           ^
```

This is expecting:

```
<a href="/Users/stackoverflow/">stackoverflow</a>
```

ie another slash just before the closing quote marks of the href attribute, as in stackoverflow/">

So it will never match.